# EJB / JAX-RS: get user principal name and check roles

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, authorization, jax-rs, interceptor

### Checking principal name and roles

Within a JEE application, I need to be able to get the **user principal name** and check **roles** in a unified way (for an interceptor I wrote, which derives function privileges from the roles and checks those instead of the roles).

For **EJBs**, I know I can access them over the `SessionContext` (`EJBContext`), and for **JAX-RS web endpoints** I can use the `SecurityContext`.

When intercepting calls to the web endpoints, the `EJBContext` is not set (Naming exception looking up the `EJBContext`). So within my interceptor, I would need to fallback to using the JAX-RS SecurityContext.

**Is there a way to look up the principal name and check roles without having to check the EJBContext and SecurityContext?**

### Fallback plan

If not, I'm considering using lookups to get either context.
As resource/context injection does not work optionally (will fail when either context is unavailable), I would have to lookup the contexts (`SessionContext`, `SecurityContext`) programmatically.

The `SessionContext` can be looked up with:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
SessionContext sessionContext = (SessionContext) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/sessionContext");
```

**Can I look up the `SecurityContext` in a similar fashion?**

Comment: Are you using CDI? Are you doing (or plan to do) remote invocations (meaning RMI, not JAX-RS) on the EJB?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: yes, I'm using CDI as well as local and also remote EJBs.

Comment: I was thinking of a couple of components cooperating for this. A web/JAX-RS filter intercepts JAX-RS calls and adds a `UserData` object to a thread-local. Then a CDI producer for the `UserData` object searches the thread-local variable: if it's there, it uses it. Otherwise it retrieves the `SessionContext` from the JNDI and creates the `UserData` from it. The security interceptor @Injects the `UserData`. Just some random thoughts actually...